# Jqueryui draggable is leaving classes on my elements. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I enable draggability like this:

```
test.draggable();
test.draggable('enable');
```

When I am done.  I disable it like this:

```
test.draggable('disable');
```

This works great in terms of making test draggable and not draggable.

Howerver, after making something draggable and then not draggable, there are classes left on `test` from jqueryui.

These classes wouldn't bother me so much, except that it sets the opacity to `opacity: .35`.  This breaks my page.

I can post any thing relevant.

From the CSS inspector:

```
.ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled {
    opacity: 0.35;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code, or part of it?

Comment: if there is any way you could refactor this into a jsfiddle, it would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes will remain as long as the draggable widget is not [destroyed](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy), and you're only disabling it, not destroying it.

If you do not need the widgets after you're done, you can write:

```
test.draggable("destroy");
```

And the classes will be removed.

Comment: @mark, the opacity rule is applied because you disabled the widget (semi-transparency is sometimes used as a visual hint that a component is disabled). The widget will remain fully opaque if you don't disable it.

Comment: @mark, I don't see anything related to this in the documentation, but the CSS rules mentions `.ui-state-disabled` as a rule trigger. If that CSS rule comes from the jQuery UI theme file and not from your custom styles, then it's the "official" behavior.